# How to make the st,nd,rd,th as superscript along with date and time in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, superscript, dateformatter

How to make the st,nd,rd,th as supescript along with date and time in swift xcode 13.
I have set the items in the tableviewcell

From the tableView cell I'm setting the date and time like in below code

```
let date = meetingListArray[indexPath.row].callScheduleDate?.dateConversion(date: meetingListArray[indexPath.row].callScheduleDate ?? "") ?? ""
        let toTime = meetingListArray[indexPath.row].timeTo?.timeConverter(date: meetingListArray[indexPath.row].timeTo ?? "") ?? ""
        let fromTime = meetingListArray[indexPath.row].timeFrom?.timeConverter(date: meetingListArray[indexPath.row].timeFrom ?? "") ?? ""
        let time = fromTime + " -" + toTime
        cell.callDateAndTime.text = date  + time
```

I have written the the dateFormatWithSuffix(), daySuffix() as extension

```
 func dateFormatWithSuffix() -> String {
            return "MMMM dd'\(self.daySuffix())' yyyy  | "
        }

        func daySuffix() -> String {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(.day, from: self)
            let dayOfMonth = components.day
            switch dayOfMonth {
            case 1, 21, 31:
                return "st"
            case 2, 22:
                return "nd"
            case 3, 23:
                return "rd"
            default:
                return "th"
            }
        }
```

I have added the image of date and time here
[image: Image of date and time]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is with an Attributed string.

For example (using your `daySuffix()` func):

```
    let someDate: Date = Date()

    let df = DateFormatter()

    // use DateFormatter and/or Calendar Components to get
    //  Month Name, dayOfMonth, year (as Strings)
    df.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let m: String = df.string(from: someDate)
    
    df.dateFormat = "d"
    let d: String = df.string(from: someDate)

    df.dateFormat = "yyyy"
    let y: String = df.string(from: someDate)
    
    // get the day suffix
    let dsf = someDate.daySuffix()
    
    // however you parse/format your to/from times
    let theTimePart: String = "12:00 AM - 12:00 AM"
    
    // font for everything except the superscript
    let font1: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .regular)
    // font for the superscript (slightly smaller)
    let font2: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 8.0, weight: .regular)
    
    // atributes for "main" part of string
    let mainAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font1]
    
    // atributes for "superscript" part of string
    //  baselineOffset of the difference between the two font sizes
    //  seems to work fairly well
    let superscriptAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font2, .baselineOffset: (font1.pointSize - font2.pointSize)]

    // first part will be (for example) "August 17" with main attributes
    let firstPart = NSMutableAttributedString(string: m + " \(d)", attributes: mainAttributes)
    // second part will be the day suffix (st,nd,th,rd) with superscript attributes
    let secondPart = NSAttributedString(string: dsf, attributes: superscriptAttributes)
    // third part will be (for example) " 2022 | 12:00 AM - 12:00 AM" with main attributes
    let thirdPart = NSAttributedString(string: " \(y) | \(theTimePart)", attributes: mainAttributes)
    
    // append second part
    firstPart.append(secondPart)
    // append third part
    firstPart.append(thirdPart)
    
    // set the label's attributed text
    cell.callDateAndTime.text = firstPart
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the same code of @[DonMag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag)
There is a small Correction.

```
cell.callDateAndTime.text = firstPart
//instead of this line  use
cell.callDateAndTime.attributedText = firstPart
```

Because we can't assign a  NSAttributedString to a label.There will be an error if you  use .text.
"Cannot assign value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' to type 'String?'".